# Passing an object to the view in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can I pass an object to the view like this?
I am getting a 404 error when I do this.

In my MoviesController I have :

```
[Route("movies/movieDetail/{id}/{name}/{x}")]
        public ActionResult movieDetail(string id, string name, Movie x)
        {
            //return Content(@"This is movie with id: " + id + @" and name : " + name);
            return Content(@"This is movie with id: " + x.Id + @" and name : " + x.Name);
        }
```

In the index view I have :

```
@model List<Vidly.Models.Movie>
<tbody>
           @foreach (var movie in Model)
              {
                  <tr>
                     <td> <a href="/Movies/movieDetail/@movie.Id/@movie.Name/@movie"> @movie.Name </a></td>
                  </tr>
              }

</tbody>
```

My idea was when I click on the link it will take me to movieDetail, but when I do that I get a 404.

Can someone please explain why this is?

Comment: Not without the url you're using as an example

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I am simply following a udemy video on mvc. I was just playing around with one of the exercises on there. Just wondering why this method wont work.  If I dont have the third argument it works fine.

Comment: without knowing what the url is, we can't tell you why it's getting a 404.  The url is key, and is not inconsequential.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch sorry I misunderstood ur question.. url is : http://localhost:50877/Movies/movieDetail/1/Shrek/Vidly.Models.Movie

Comment: Well, there's your problem.  Vidly.Models.Movie is not a valid movie object.  That's it's type name.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch how can I pass it as a valid movie object.

Comment: I guess i am wondering if there is a way to pass the movie directly rather than passing the id of the movie and get the detail of that movie from that id.

Comment: Yes, there is.  But it's not recommended.  The recommended way is to do just what you say you don't want to do.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch oh ok. If I want to do it that way how would I go about doing that?.. Just so i can learn

Comment: Your controller is expecting a movie object as the parameter but you can't do that using `GET` style routing with `[Route("movies/movieDetail/{id}/{name}/{x}")]`  The `x` needs to be a string (or something simple like an int which can be cast).  Movie is a complex object.  If you want to pass a `Movie` _into_ the method then you'll need to use a `POST` method not a `GET`.

Comment: You would need to serialize the object to a string, and pass it as a string, then deserialize it on the other side.. it's just not very feasible.

Comment: What is your `Movie` model. If it contains properties `int Id` and `string Name`, then just use `href="Url.Action("MovieDetail", "Movie", new { id = movie.Id, name = movie.Name })` and `public ActionResult movieDetail(Movie x)` and the parameter will be initialized an bound with the values you passed

Comment: And if `Movie` just contains simple properties, the it can be just `@Url.Action("MovieDetail", "Movie", movie)`

Comment: Thanks everyone for explaining it to me. really appreciate it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke btw when i try it the way you suggested. I get a null reference exception.  It doesn't seem to be getting initialized and bound with the values that are being passed in

Comment: It will be. But you have not shown the new code your trying so I cannot guess what mistakes you made.

Comment: <td> <a href="@Url.Action("MovieDetail", "Movies", new { Id = movie.Id, Name = movie.Name })"> @movie.Name </a></td>

Comment: [Route("movies/movieDetail/{x}")]
        public ActionResult movieDetail(Movie x)
        {
            var xx = x;

            //return Content(@"This is movie with id: " + id + @" and name : " + name);
            return Content(@"This is movie with id: " + x.Id + @" and name : " + x.Name);
        }

Comment: thats what i changed it to. but i get a null reference exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151118/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-psj01).